# Searching for strings in a list which contain a specific word

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a code in Python 2.7 in which I have defined a list of more then a million strings. Here is my simple code to find the strings that contain a keyword:

```
for word in wordlist:
   if keyword in word:
      newlist.append(word)
```

Is there a better/faster way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to be doing this often? Are you only matching exact words? It might be worth building and keeping an index:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Index:
    def __init__(self, stringlist):
        self.index = defaultdict(list)
        for string in stringlist:
            for word in string.split():
                self.index[word].append(string)

    def strings_containing(self, word):
        return self.index[word]
```

Comment: Yes I'm only matching exact words. Efficient way, thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use comprehension like this

```
newlist = [word for word in wordlist if keyword in word]
```

Comment: Better way, but not faster.